# Can the threadpool thread that's waiting on a set of Tasks end up serving one of those other Tasks?

Tags: .net, multithreading, threadpool

Suppose you have a set of sub-tasks created like so:

```
var childTasks = new List<Task<ResultType>>();
for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    var childTask = new Task<ResultType>(() => {  logic here  });
    childTasks.Add(childTask);
    childTask.Start();
}
```

If some logical operation "A" was itself started as a Task and is running in a ThreadPool thread which we've named "A", and it calls `Task.WaitAll(childTasks.Select(x => (Task)x).ToArray()); //cast Task<T> to Task and make array as required by Task.WaitAll`, is there ANY chance that ThreadPool thread "A" is returned to the pool during the WaitAll operation and used to serve one of the child tasks?  In other words, is there any chance that a childTask will end up running on the same thread pool thread that the calling task was using?

Or, does WaitAll block the current thread and prevent it from returning to the pool?

Comment: `Wait*()`s are blocking calls.

Comment: We're seeing an issue where a Task initiating another Task has thread cross-talk, but when using new Thread() which calls the Task, there is no cross-talk. We're seeing items that are stored keyed on Thread.Name (which is Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) retrieving the calling thread's value.  It's as if the child tasks are somehow running on the caller's thread and disposing an object it owns, such that when returning to the calling thread (i.e. WaitAll returns), the object associated with it's thread name is gone, presumably disposed by a child task that got the same thread at some point.

Comment: In rare cases (especially inside VS extensions), you can get reentrancy from the COM event loop.

Answer (score 1):

A will not be returned. Your code is still on the stack. This is fundamentally so.

But task inlining can occur. Anytime you wait for a Task the TPL can directly execute that task on the current thread. This is an efficiency optimization. It is also, in my not so humble opinion, an egregious design bug. It means that waiting on any task can, in practice, execute arbitrary code at that point. This is very unpredictable.

`childTask.Start()` will not do this, since it does not wait, but all the wait functions can do this. It's terrible. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2454